# Non backtracking random walk - probability to land in subset

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

Given a finite, undirected, 2-connected graph $G = (V,E)$, a non-backtracking random walk on $G$ is a random walk on the vertices of $G$ that "cannot backtrack". That is, if the walk $P$ is of size $k$, then $P = (u_0, u_1, \ldots, u_{k-1})$ is such that $(u_i, u_{i+1}) \in E$ and $u_{i+2} \neq u_i$.

The question that I am interested in is the following: given some $S \subseteq V$, find
$$ \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \Pr[u_k \in S] $$
That is, what is the probability that the random walk ends at a node from $S$?

In general, non-backtracking random walk is not a Markov chain, and I guess that there is no simple answer. I try to understand what happens in a specific case, but even that seems hard:

Suppose that $G$ is a cycle on $n$ vertices (so the vertex set is $[n]$ and there is an edge for all $(i, i+1)$ and $(0,n)$), and that we added an edge "in the middle", that is we add the edge $(0, \frac{n}{2})$. Suppose that $S = \{0, \frac{n}{2}\}$. Can we compute the probability that the non-backtracking random walk will be in $S$ after $k \rightarrow \infty$ steps?

Comment: Your example in the final paragraph helps to illustrate the difficulty here; your process will both visit and leave $S$ infinitely many times with probability 1, so I'm not sure how you'd hope to assess something like "the probability that the walk will be in $S$ after $k \to \infty$ steps." Even for just an ordinary simple random walk on that graph, you'd have to define the question differently -- maybe you mean "proportion of time spent in $S$" or something? Or maybe you intend to have some terminal states (that aren't present in your example)?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Thanks for the reply. For a "normal" random walk we get a markov chain, which has a stationary distribution, which intuitively describes the probability to be at some node after "a while". In that case the answer to my question would be summing the "S coordinates" in the stationary distribution

Comment: The Markov Chain *might* have a stationary distribution, but even then it's complicated; for instance, a random walk on an $n$-cycle with even $n$ will have a periodicity problem. (This is fairly easily solved by just discussing the even and odd states separately, of course.) At any rate, back to your original question: your process on the $n$-cycle will just cycle around in one direction infinitely; if you add a bridge in the middle, it will just alternate (randomly) between the two halves. My gut says it's quite hard to say anything *general* here, but I'm not quite sure.